# Synchronized loading data in tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, tableview, loading

I want to load data through parser rss which is working fine. Though it loads the data and then displays it which leaves a gap of a couple of seconds for the app to populate the table. So from that you press the button *load tableview* it takes a few seconds for it to open because it loads the data and then display it.

I want to be able to have a loading screen that opens up and displays *loading data* and when the table is populated, the table is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the HUD libraries available out there.
Here is one that I like https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD